# How to send email in ruby on rails I have created demo email but it only creates the new user but it was not send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this file `User_controllers.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json

  def create
    # Create the user from params
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      # Deliver the signup email
      UserNotifier.send_signup_email(@user).deliver
      redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User created')
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :login)
end
```

end

Comment: https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails this might help you

Comment: read AcionMailer from rails guide also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

1.If you use rails4 you must use `deliver_now` instead  `deliver`

2.Set your mail config

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: "example.com",
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

3. You need to install post client in your system. Ubuntu -[postfix](http://www.postfix.org/)